# How to match a whole line with or without '\n' using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match all comments in a text file and I use the following regex to match single line comment:

```
//(.*?)\r?\n
```

But it could not match the last line if the last line is a single comment line such as:

```
// test
```

so, how to write a single regex to match a whole line that with or without '\n' in C#, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to include the `//` double slash in the beginning?

Comment: If you do not care about lines like `var s = "//sometext"; // some comment`, then you may use [`(?m)//(.+)\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%2f%2f(.%2b)%5cr%3f%24&i=%2f%2f+test%0d%0astring+m+%3d+%22new+text%22%3b+%2f%2f+comment). To "trim" the captured text, use [`(?m)//(.*?)\p{Zs}*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%2f%2f(.*%3f)%5cp%7bZs%7d*%24&i=%2f%2f+test%0d%0astring+m+%3d+%22new+text%22%3b+%2f%2f+comment+).

Answer (score 0):

You could write your regex as:

```
//(.*?)\r?$
```

The `$` sign will match the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider this instead:

```
//(.*)\s*$
```

This will exclude any trailing whitespace (including newlines) from your capture group.  I assume you wouldn't care about capturing trailing spaces.

The limitations of a regex to match comments are important to keep in mind: it will match some non-comment items in code.  For example, consider this line:

```
get_web_page('http://www.foo.com');
```

If you only want to match comments on their own line, you could do this:

```
^\s*//(.*)\s*$
```

If you need to match comments that come after code, as well, the above problem can't be overcome easily with a regex.

**Update:** I am assuming that your code iterates through the file line by line, the most common case.  However, if you have the entire file in a string and are matching the regex against that, you can enable multi-line mode for this to work.

Comment: `^` and `$` specifies start and end of string not line

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, that depends on how the regex is used within the code, which is not shown.  If the code iterates through the file line by line, this will work.  If the whole file is in an entire string, it will still work if multi-line mode is enabled.  I have clarified the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify new line because `.` matches any character except new line.

```
//(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^/s*?//([^\s]*?)/s*?$
```

a whole line start with '^' and end with '$', and some other white space characters '/s'

Answer (score 0):

The last line does not contain  a newline at the end, that is why your `//(.*?)\r?\n` regex fails.

You need to use a non-capturing group with a `$` anchor as an alternative:

```
//(.*?)(?:\r?\n|$)
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%2f%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%24%29&i=....+%2f%2f+test+0%0d%0a....+%2f%2f+test). Results:

[image]